# MySQL Granting privileges to a user

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been playing around with creating a new user and I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON `testingUser' at line 3

and my query is:

```
mysql_query("

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON `$user\_database`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT (Table_priv, Column_priv, Table_name, Db, User, Host) ON `mysql`.`tables_priv` TO '$user'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`host` TO '$user'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT (Host, Create_priv, Shutdown_priv, Delete_priv, User, Process_priv, Reload_priv, Alter_priv, Super_priv, Grant_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_client_priv, Insert_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Lock_tables_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, File_priv, Drop_priv, Show_db_priv, Select_priv, Update_priv) ON `mysql`.`user` TO '$user'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`db` TO '$user'@'localhost';");
```

Comment: `mysql_query` cannot execute multiple queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot issue multiple queries in a single `mysql_query()` call. It's a security restriction to prevent some forms of SQL injection. You'll have to issue each grant query in a separate `mysql_query()` call.

```
mysql_query("GRANT ...");
mysql_query("GRANT ...");
etc...
```